# How to plot replace numbers with letters on Matplotlib subplot axis?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm plotting a basic sine wave in Matplotlib. Is there a general way to replace the numbers on the y-axis with letters? I want to replace the -1.0, -0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0 labels with just -V_0, 0, and V_0.

This is my code.

```
v1 = np.sin(ang_freq * times) #V_0sin(wt)
v2 = ang_freq * np.cos(ang_freq * times)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, sharex = True)
fig.suptitle('Sinusoidal driving wave')

axs[0].plot(times, v1)
axs[0].set_title('Input voltage $V_1$')
axs[0].set_ylabel('Voltage / V')
axs[0].autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=True)

axs[1].plot(times, v2)
axs[1].set_title('Output voltage $V_2$')
axs[1].set_ylabel('Voltage / V')
axs[1].autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=True)
plt.xlabel('Times / s')
plt.show()
```

Comment: See [fancy tick formats](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.10-customizing-ticks.html#Fancy-Tick-Formats)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is [`axis.set_yticks()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yticks.html) change it your 3 values, -V0, 0, V0. And then call [`axis.set_yticklabels()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticklabels.html) to set a text for each of those. Note the warning that you should label the ticks after changing said list to avoid any unexpected results.

```
ang_freq = np.pi
times = np.linspace(0, 5)

v1 = np.sin(ang_freq * times) #V_0sin(wt)
v2 = ang_freq * np.cos(ang_freq * times)
v = np.vstack([v1, v2])

fig, axs = plt.subplots(v.shape[0], sharex = True)
fig.suptitle('Sinusoidal driving wave')

for i, ax in enumerate(axs):
    ax.plot(times, v[i])
    ax.set_title('Input voltage $V_{}$'.format(i+1))
    ax.set_ylabel('Voltage / V')
    ax.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=True)
    ax.set_yticks([min(v[i]), 0, max(v[i])])
    ax.set_yticklabels(['$-V_0$', '0', '$V_0$'])

plt.xlabel('Times / s')
plt.show()
```

[image]